# Cascode amplifier does not provide gain properly

Tags: amplifier, inductor, cascode, ads

I'm trying to build a Cascode amplifier on ads but I think I have a problem with my tank oscilator. Here's the complete circuit

[image: Cascode Circuit on ADS]

The inductor is an air-core inductor from coilcraft and the transistor is a bc547.
The problem with this circuit is the output:

[image: vout]

Which is barelly oscilating at all. Here's the input for comparisson:

[image: vin and vout plot]

Can anyone help me diagnose this ? The ressonance frequency is 250kHz (which I think is what is causing me trouble).

Comment: 53 uF? Drop the capacitor 3 or 4 orders of magnitude and increase L likewise. Or replace the tuned circuit with a current source.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have limited Inductors at hand, this is the highest one (Inductance wise) of them that can sustain a good Q at 250kHz. Maybe I will try something else then.

Comment: Inductors are easy; wind your own.

Comment: Note that the load is "generally" wired with a serial capacitor ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 53 μF tank capacitor is more suitable for sub-audio filtering. It's completely inappropriate for an amplifier operating at 250 kHz.

Something like 4.05 nF and 100 μH is more like the values you need for your tank circuit.

Other than that, you biasing levels look good to go.